# How can I make a dropdown menu close when I open another one in Vuejs 3

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I have two components dropdowns menu in a component and I want to close one when the other is open I'm new to Vuejs so I don't want to use any plugin, if anyone could help me with this? here's my actual code:

**NavShop.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="nav-shop" >
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">صفحه نخست</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href=""><drop-down-brand /></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href=""><drop-down-accessory /></a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">گارانتی و خدمات</a></li>
        <li><a href="">وبلاگ</a></li>
        <li><a href="">درباره ما</a></li>
        <li><a href="">تماس با ما</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</template>
```

**DropDownBrand.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="dropdown-container" @click="openList">
    <a href="#">برند</a>
    <img class="down-icon" src="src/assets/photo/icons8-arrow-24.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <transition name="brand" appear>
    <div class="brand-menu" v-if="close" >
      <div class="item-brand" v-for="(brand, index) in brands" :key="index">
        <a class="name-brand" href="">{{ brand }}</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </transition>
</template>
<script>
import closeListMenu from '../composable/dropDownMenu.js';
export default {
  name: "DropDownBrand",

  setup() {
    const brands = [
      "honda",
      "kavir",
      "yamaha",
      "honda",
      "kavir",
      "yamaha",
      "honda",
      "kavir",
      "yamaha",
    ];
    const { close, openList, mounted, closed} = closeListMenu();


    return {
      brands,
      close,
      openList,
      mounted,
      closed
    
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

**DropDownAccessory.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="dropdown-acc" @click="openList">
    <a href="#">لوازم جانبی</a>
    <img class="down-icon" src="src/assets/photo/icons8-arrow-24.png" alt="" />
  </div>
  <transition name="acc">
    <div class="acc-menu" v-if="close" >
      <div>
        <header>ایپسوم</header>
        <div
          class="items-acc"
          v-for="(accessory, index) in accessories"
          :key="index"
        >
          <a class="name-acc" href="">{{ accessory }}</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <header>موتور سیکلت</header>
        <div class="items-acc" v-for="(acc, index) in accMotor" :key="index">
          <a class="name-acc" href="">{{ acc }}</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </transition>
</template>
<script>
import closeListMenu from '../composable/dropDownMenu';
export default {
  name: "DropDownAccessory",
  setup() {
    const accessories = [
      "کلاه ایمنی",
      "دستکش",
      "کلاه ایمنی",
      "دستکش",
      "کلاه ایمنی",
      "دستکش",
      "کلاه ایمنی",
      "دستکش",
      "کلاه ایمنی",
      "دستکش",
    ];
    const accMotor = ["کلاه ایمنی", "دستکش", "کلاه ایمنی"];

    const {close , openList} = closeListMenu()

    return {
      accessories,
      accMotor,
      close,
      openList,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

This is composable:

**dropDownMenu.js**

```
import { ref } from "vue";


export default  function closeListMenu() {
    const close = ref(false);
    function openList(e){
        close.value = !close.value;
    };
    

    function closed (e) {
        if (!this.$el.contains(e.target)) {
          this.close.value = false
        }
      };
    
    function mounted () {
      document.addEventListener('click', this.close)
    };
   
    function beforeDestroy () {
      document.removeEventListener('click',this.close)
    };
   
    return {
        openList,
        close,
        closed,
        mounted,
        beforeDestroy,
      };
}
```

Function closed does not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
You could set other styles for codes.
```

The code uses active to control the elements show and hide.Of course,using specail class and styles can do that like this.

```js
import {ref} from 'vue'
const active = ref(0)
const menuList = [
  {label:"menu1",subMenu:[
    {label:"sub1-1"},
    {label:"sub1-2"},
    {label:"sub1-3"},
  ]},
  {label:"menu2",subMenu:[
    {label:"sub2-1"},
    {label:"sub2-2"},
    {label:"sub2-3"},
  ]},
]
```

```css
.title{
  
}

.subTitle{
  text-indent:2em
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="menu" v-for="(item,index) in menuList" :key="index">
    <div class="title" @click="active = index">{{item.label}}</div>
    <div class="subMenuList" v-if="active==index">
      <div class="subTitle" v-for="(e,i) in item.subMenu" :key="i">{{e.label}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```